# How to get and display last updated field id in Laravel

Tags: laravel-4

I have a table `total_count` with the following structure:

```
id  studid  month   year     acls_id   total_p  total_a 

1   30       08     2015        12        5       2         
2   35       08     2015        12        5       2         
3   52       08     2015        12        5       2         
4   53       08     2015        12        5       2     
5   54       08     2015        12        5       2     
6   55       08     2015        12        5       2     
7   30       09     2015        12        3       0
```

In my view page, this table displays a list of all `studid` with their details.

Here is my edit method in controller.php:

```
foreach ($student as $student) {
   $queryt= DB::table($wys_attendence_table)->where('studid', $student->id)
        ->where('adate', $date_exploded[0])
        ->where('amonth', $date_exploded[1])
        ->where('ayear', $date_exploded[2])
        ->update(array(
            'attendence'=>Input::get($student->id),
        ));
}
```

My edit function works.

```
$lastUpdatedId= $queryt->id;
$lastUpdatedStudid= $queryt->studid;
var_dump($lastUpdatedId);
var_dump($lastUpdatedStudid);
```

Does not work..

How to get and display updated field `id` and `studid` value.

for eg: if I am editing `studid`=30 and `studid`=52,

I want to display `id`=1,3 and `studid` = 30,52.

Comment: You already have the id fields provided by the ```foreach``` loop - ```$student->id```. You can use it to send new queries to ```SELECT``` from the database the updated rows.

Comment: thank you sir.yes , i did i got answer